# Munin with Nginx and FastCGI

Tags: nginx, munin

I'm trying to configure Munin over Nginx. To do so, I need to manually start the cgi process with this command:

```
spawn-fcgi -s fastcgi-graph.sock -U nginx -u nginx -g nginx /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp/munin-cgi-graph -n
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
spawn-fcgi: exec failed: Permission denied
```

The permissions on the socket file is as followed:

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 nginx nginx 0 May  2 14:08 fastcgi-graph.sock
```

Can anyone point me out on what it wrong with that configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Did not found the solution but I was able to run Munin for Nginx without `spawn-fcgi`.